# WebView does not work with local HTML files

Tags: android, html, webview

I am trying to use WebView to show a local HTML file containing a table. However, when I use the WebView to check websites online it works perfectly, the problem is when i try to use the local HTML file.

This is the webView part of the code:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.loadUrl("file:///asset/table.html");
```

I have used an online host to test the HTML file with this and it worked perfectly:
`myWebView.loadUrl("http://ahmad92billectric.host56.com//home.html");`

the HTIML file is in app\src\main\asset, I tried calling it using the following ways:

```
myWebView.loadUrl("file:///andriod_asset/table.html");
myWebView.loadUrl("file:///app/src/main/assets/table.html");
myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_assets/table.html"); //this one is assets with an s at the end
```

I looked up many questions here non of the answers worked for me:
[Loading existing .html file with android WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027701/loading-existing-html-file-with-android-webview) 
[What does file:///android_assets/www/index.html mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961975/what-does-file-android-assets-www-index-html-mean) 
[Android webview loadurl("file:///android_asset/index.html#home") failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19857225/android-webview-loadurlfile-android-asset-index-htmlhome-failed) 
[Android Studio Assets not loading Local HTML File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26119900/android-studio-assets-not-loading-local-html-file) 
I have checked many other questions with no fruitful results. I am using android studio 0.8.14

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load local HTML file into WebView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749569/load-local-html-file-into-webview)

Answer (score 1):

Use `file:///android_asset/table.html`, which is none of your listed attempts.

You can see that in use in [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/WebKit/GeoWeb1), though the file here is `geoweb1.html`:

```
  @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    browser=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webkit);

    myLocationManager=(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    browser.addJavascriptInterface(new Locater(), "locater");
    browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/geoweb1.html");
  }
```